# Fill EditText with value without kicking off Listener

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm writing some logic where an EditText view has a listener which listens for the length of the text to match 12 characters. At some stage, a user is able to come back to this stage which will fill in the EditText with a value of 12 characters as text, not a hint (needs to be text).

My issue is that the user can come back to enter in his Tag to the associated Barcode, but the Barcode get's populated into the Barcode EditText.

Would the best option to be once filling in the EditText, to remove the listener and attach it again after?

Details:

A barcode will always be 12 digits. A technician will have two inputs, a Tag, and a Barcode. He can enter a barcode and not enter a Tag to continue. When the technician comes back to enter his Tag, the Barcode get's populated which kicks off the event. How can I populate the Barcode without kicking off the event?

```
barcode.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Text.ToString().Length == 12)
            {
                if (SampleState.Instance.doesBarcodeExist(long.Parse(barcode.Text), Row))
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "That Barcode is already Associated to an Animal", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
                // Technician has both the animal number and barcode.
                else if (animalTagText.Text.Length > 0 && barcode.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    tagText = animalTagText.Text;
                    barcodeText = barcode.Text;
                    this.commitAndClean();
                }
                // Technician only has the barcode available.
                else if (animalTagText.Text.Length <= 0 && barcode.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    tagText = animalTagText.Text;
                    barcodeText = barcode.Text;
                    animalTagText.RequestFocus();
                }
            }
        };
 ...
          try {
                    if (SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).Skipped == true)
                    {
                        unitText.Text = SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).Unit.ToString();
                        animalTagText.Text = SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).Tag;

                        // This is filling the Barcode EditText after it was skipped which kicks off the event. Trying to stop this.
                        barcode.Text = SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).BarCode.ToString();

                        rowText.Text = SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).Row.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (i + 1 == SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).Count)
                    {
                        this.finshedSampling();
                    }
                }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show us code, what you wrote makes no sense to me.

Comment: Apologies, I always assume people understand, bad habit :P. Sure I'll put my code up. I just want to find a better way to stop events from kicking off. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: "which kicks off the event" what event?

Comment: .TextChanged is the event set for it. So once the Input box gets 12 digits the event get's fired. Sorry, slowly trying to explain :/

Comment: Would it be best to set the onTextChangedListener on OnCreate and then remove it once the input box is being populated?

Comment: i think the logic behind this might be wrong. allow me to explain. i go into your app, i enter a barcode, but no tag. i exit the app. i go back in, the barcode is there, but no event is fired. i see that you are on xamarin, so i cant speak for c# code, however, you want to override onResume. when I enter into the app, check to see the length of the string inside the edittext. if its == 12, fire away.

Comment: Ah, no worries about if it's C# or Java, just trying to solve the Event firing issue. You wouldn't go out of the app, should have said that sorry. Say this functionality would associate to a fragment. The fragment will have a number of inputs, Tag and Barcode being the most important. I can skip this insert stage once I but in a Barcode. When I come back after skipping, I insert my text that was saved into the Barcode so the user can enter a Tag. But when I'm inserting the Barcode here programmatically, it's firing the Event. Hope I explained that enough.

Comment: If not let me know :). I thought I was keeping it simple when creating this feature but I believe I'm just creating the wrong logic for the events. Also thanks for even going through it with me.

Comment: again, it comes down to the lifecycle of the activity (fragment). youre best bet is to store the information in either a database or in the sharedpref. then just get the information, and onCreate, if its = 12, fire.

Comment: Cool, that's fine. I have the event firing. What I am trying to do is stop it from firing when the information gets set into the Barcode EditText when it's being filled after being skipped. Once it hits 12 the first time is fine, that fires the event. If I skip inserting a Tag, I need to put information into the Barcode EditText once they are ready to fill in the Tag, but without firing the Barcode Event listening for 12 digits. Any smart way of doing it without having to set and unset a listener :/? Again thanks for your input!

Comment: use a boolean helper. if true...good, else not good. store that has a sharedpref.

Comment: Yeah, that might help. Feels like I totally made it awkward for myself. Definitely, need a rethink after this. Was thinking if others had an idea of making it better but this definitely helps. Thanks DroiDev